# Am I iterating this dictionary properly?

Tags: python, for-loop

Struggling to work out why it wont read my list as an integer? Could someone shed some light on what I seem to be missing?

Here's the challenge I was working on: Create a dictionary with 3 key:value pairs, called dict. Write a FOR Loop that loops for the length of dictionary.values(), and prints out each value.

Heres what I think I've done.

1. Created my dictionary w/ keys & values.
2. Converted my dictionary values into a list
3. Created a for loop and asked it to print each iteration.

```
dict = {
    
    'eggs' : 5, 
    'chips' : 4, 
    'ham' : 3
    
    }

dictList = list(dict.values())

for i in range(dictList):

    print(dictList[i])
```

**
Could someone explain the error to me too?**

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: `range(dictList)` -> `range(len(dictList))`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! I see where I went wrong x

Comment: You're welcome! If you have any more doubts, send me a mail to midis18206@anawalls.com.

Comment: Don't use `for i in range(len(dictList)):` use `for item in dictList:`

Comment: @enzo lists are already iterable, so you 1) don't need to iterate over the range of the length of the list, and 2) don't need to index into the list with 1dictList[i]` - as @Barmar said, you can (and should) just use `for item in dictList: print(item)`

Comment: @JRiggles Stop being pedantic. You don't know the methodology of OP's tutor. You don't know if OP was used to code in Java and is gradually moving to Python. Focus on the problem the OP is giving. Also, I added that as a comment, not as an answer, so if you want to be more detailed add a freaking ANSWER.

Comment: And yes, I agree that `for item in dictList:` is the Pythonic way of doing it, but telling what was wrong with the OP code is certainly more useful than presuming his knowledge about the language.

Comment: @enzo I did add an answer. And also I might argue that programming is all about being pedantic (or at the very least, precise). You shouldn't teach OP anti-patterns based on assumptions you're making about how OP was tutored. They're asking about Python, so making guesses about them coming from Java is moot.

Comment: I can't wait for all those people searching "New to Python - Can someone shed some light?" to find this answer about iterating dict items. @JRiggles is right to be pedantic. This isn't a tutorial forum (or, at least, it didn't start out that way). If you want to correct users, you should do it fully

Comment: @JRiggles I shouldn't make guesses about OP coming from Java and you also shouldn't make guesses about OP knowing what's Pythonic or not. What all of us should do is to point what was wrong with their code and try to do as beginner-friendly as possible.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, of course a beginner having trouble with dictionaries will use that exact search query.

Comment: @enzo what do they search for when they have list problems?

Comment: @roganjosh Maybe "how to iterate over a list in Python" or "accessing index of a list Python", surely not "can someone shed some light".

Comment: @enzo then I'm totally lost on your stance here. You're agreeing that the title is ambiguous (it would be a dupe too) but you quite aggressively goaded someone into answering anyway. If you wanted this to be answered properly then either find the dupe or edit the title (and then find the dupe)

Comment: Question is answered. I'm new to this but I'm not stupid. @JRiggles had the right approach to the post. First time I've ever used stack overflow so unsure about the war waged on the posts title. Will consider my wording / question carefully in future. Every day's a school day.

Comment: @plasticmicky there's no particular reason this one question should be the flashpoint other than a meeting of personalities, but your title is not helpful in any case. Your misunderstanding is fine, but the whole point of Stack Overflow is to be a repository of useful information for posterity in a Q&A format so it'd be good to think about how to generalise your problem and name it with something specific. This is the root of why many people find asking on SO quite stressful - it's not just about you

Comment: Thanks @roganjosh - Will take this on board, I've amended the title to hopefully help others with a similar question!

Comment: @plasticmicky I like “Every day's a school day" - that's especially true around here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert `my_dict` into a list, as you can just iterate over `my_dict.values()`. Since `list`s in Python are already iterable (that is, they can be looped over), you 1) don't need to iterate over the range of the length of the list, and 2) don't need to index into the list with `dictList[i]`

Instead, you can simply do the following:

```
my_dict = {
    'eggs' : 5, 
    'chips' : 4, 
    'ham' : 3
}

for value in my_dict.values():
    print(value)
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain what is meant by iterate\iterable please?

Comment: @plasticmicky It's a hundred-dollar term for a one-cent concept. Stick with `for i in range(len(dictList))` for now. People here hate beginners and try to force their advanced terms all over the place.

Comment: @plasticmicky Sure! In programming, to "iterate" over something just means to go through the items in the list one by one and perform some operation on them (in Python this usually means a `list` or some other sequence of items). By the same token, "iterable" just means "something that is able to be iterated over".

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @JRiggles

Comment: @enzo it's literally the correct word for the concept in question. Stop being difficult for the for the sake of it. If you want beginners to learn, it's better to teach them the correct concepts and words rather than teaching them non-pythonic techniques just because *you* think it might be easier for them to understand. I don't hate beginners, we were all beginners at one point and there's always opportunity to learn.

Comment: @plasticmicky Glad I could help! I know this site can be contentious sometimes - enzo is right about one thing: people here often shut down beginners as a matter of course, but we all have to start somewhere.

Comment: @JRiggles So you explain about quantum physics to a high-school student just "for the sake of learning"?

Comment: @enzo This isn't a question about quantum physics. Stop being an ass. Go home. Iteration is a beginner-level concept, and there's no reason not to use it or teach someone about it.

Comment: I'd like to mention that "create a dictionary called `dict`" is a very bad part of the task. [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) is a built-in in Python and shouldn't be overwritten.

Comment: @Matthias that’s a good point! I’ll change it here.